# Запись и чтение бинарного файла

Tags: java, файлы, swing, io

Записываю файл следующим образом:

```
EmployeeRandomRecord record = new EmployeeRandomRecord();

record.setId(id);
record.setPps(pps);
record.setName(firstName);
record.setSurname(surname);
record.setGender(gender);
record.setDep(dep);
record.setSalary(salary);
record.setFulltime(fulltime);


RandomAccessFile file = new   RandomAccessFile("employees.dat", "rw");

file.seek(( id - 1 ) * EmployeeRandomRecord.SIZE);
record.write(file);
file.close();
```

Далее мне необходимо открыть данный файл, считать всю информацию, и отобразить в программе в `JTextField`

Открываю файл:

```
openItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");

            fileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Action");
              }
            });

            int status = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);


            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

              EmployeeRandomRecord record = new EmployeeRandomRecord();
              record.seek(currentItem);

              try {
                   DataInputStream inStream                               // Open stream
                     = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("employees.dat"));
                    idTextField.setText(record.getId() + "");
                    ppsTextField.setText(record.getPps());
                    nameTextField.setText(record.getName());
                    surnameTextField.setText(record.getSurname());
                    genderTextField.setText(record.getGender());
                    depTextField.setText(record.getDep());
                    salaryTextField.setText(record.getSalary() + "");
                    fulltimeTextField.setText(record.getFullTime());
                    try {
                      while (true) {                                       
                        displayDetails(currentItem);
                      } // while
                    } catch (EOFException ee) {                             // Until EOF exception
                    } finally {
                       inStream.close();                                  // Close the stream
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ee) {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot find file");
                } catch (IOException ee) {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot open file");
                }

             } else if (status == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("calceled");
             }
          }
    });
```

Пытаюсь отобразить данные:

```
public void displayDetails(int currentItem) throws IOException{

            Employee em = new Employee();

            file.seek(currentItem*NUMBER_RECORDS);
            em.setId(file.readInt());
            em.setPps(file.read() + "");
            em.setName(file.read() + "");
            em.setSurname(file.read() + "");
            em.setGender(file.read() + "");
            em.setDep(file.read() + "");
            em.setSalary(file.readInt());
            em.setFulltime(file.read() + "");

            idTextField.setText(em.getId() + "");
            ppsTextField.setText(em.getPps());
            nameTextField.setText(em.getName());
            surnameTextField.setText(em.getSurname());
            genderTextField.setText(em.getGender());
            depTextField.setText(em.getDep());
            salaryTextField.setText(em.getSalary() + "");
            fulltimeTextField.setText(em.getFullTime());

        }
```

Думаю ошибка в отображении данных. Никак не могу написать правильно, и присвоить `int currentItem`, чтобы приложение не выдавало никаких ошибок.
Программа на не читает данные и выдает следующее в консоле:

```
Action
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Файлы должны отобразиться в следующем методе:

```
        public void displayDetails(int currentItem) throws IOException{

            int id = 0;
            Employee em = new Employee();


            currentItem = (int) file.getFilePointer();
            record.read(file);
            record.seek(( id - 1 ) * EmployeeRandomRecord.SIZE); 
            idTextField.setText(record.getId() + "");
            ppsTextField.setText(record.getPps());
            nameTextField.setText(record.getName());
            surnameTextField.setText(record.getSurname());
            genderTextField.setText(record.getGender() + "");
            depTextField.setText(record.getDep());
            salaryTextField.setText(record.getSalary() + "");
            fulltimeTextField.setText(record.getFullTime() + "");

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь у вас "мертвый" цикл.

```
while (true) {                                       
  displayDetails(currentItem);
}
```

Вы надеетесь, что из него выйдете по исключению, но похоже что исключение не возникает. А не возникает оно вероятней всего из-за того что значение переменной `currentItem` внутри этого цикла никак не изменяется.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Проблема действительно была в этом. ВЫ случайно не знаете как можно определить позицию - `currentItem` - `random access` файла. т.е.я обновила вопрос, там находиться метод, который должен отобразить данные, но теперь видимо он не работает.